# parametrization of upper unit sphere

Tags: manifolds, spheres, parametrization

I know, there have been multiple questions posed about sphere coordinates, but I state that mine is a little different:

originating from a manifold given by M = $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert x^2+y^2+z^2=1,\quad z\geq0\}$ that describes a unit sphere u can find the simple parametrization:

$\psi_1(x,y)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}x\\y\\\sqrt{1-x^2-z^2}\end{array}\right)$

or with spheric coordinates:

$\psi_2(r,\varphi)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}r\,\cos(\varphi)\\r\,\sin(\varphi)\\\sqrt{1-r^2}\end{array}\right) \quad \text{where}\quad r\in[0,1], \varphi \in[0,2\pi]$

Now, I wonder how this should equal to the usual sphere coordinates:

$\psi_3(\varphi,\theta)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}r\,\cos(\varphi)\,r\,\sin(\theta)\\r\,\sin(\varphi)\,r\,\sin(\theta)\\r\,\cos(\theta)\end{array}\right)\quad \text{where}\quad r=1, \varphi \in[0,2\pi], \theta\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

especially because the parametrization depends on different parameter.

How are they equal to each other. Or are they at all?

Comment: The second is in cylindrical coordinates. Third is in spherical coordinates but you should substitute $r = 1$ in third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can describe the set $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ using 3 different geometries, these are Cartesian (usual), cylindrical and spherical geometry. Among these geometries, the way of describing a point in space changes, but they are equivalent, since there are bijective transformations to go from one to the other.

For example: From cylindrical to Cartesian coordinates
\begin{eqnarray*}
    f:  \mathbb{R}^3  & \to     &  \mathbb{R}^3\\
        (\rho,\phi,z) & \mapsto & f(\rho,\phi,z)=(\rho\cos(\phi),\rho\sin(\phi),z)=(x,y,z)
\end{eqnarray*}
this function is a biyection for $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$, $\rho\geq 0$ and $z\in\mathbb{R}$.

The above allows writing different regions through parameterizations that may be easier.

Comment: Thanks, now it comes together. Furthermore, is it right that I can't change parametrisation, after I formed the unit normal vector? In other words the unit normal vector of the sphere in cylindric coordinates ($\psi_2$) can't be transformed to the one in sphere coordinates $\psi_3$ just by substituting $r = r\,\sin(\varphi)$?

Even if this sounds like a contradiction

Comment: You can describe each unit vector of a coordinate system as the linear combination of unit vectors of another system, continuing with the example I gave before we have to: $\hat{\rho}=\hat{x}\cos\phi+\hat{y}\sin\phi$ and $\hat{\theta}=-\hat{x}\sin\phi+\hat{y}\cos\phi$. @Leon

Comment: It is possible to verify that $\{\hat{\rho},\hat{\phi},\hat{z}\}$ is a ortonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.  But it should be noted that $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $(\rho,\phi,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\times[0,2\pi)\times\mathbb{R}$, and the set $\mathbb{R}^{+}\times [0,2\pi)\times\mathbb {R}$ is not vector space, but is isomorphic, then change the arithmetic a bit. The previous idea is applicable to your problem, here I attach the unit vectors of the usual coordinate systems @Leon

Comment: [Unit vectors of the usual coordinate systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector#Spherical_coordinates) @Leon

Comment: thank you! That sheet was answering exactly what I was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

The second one can be easily transformed into the third one using $r\in[0,1]\to R\sin\theta$, with $R=1$ on the right hand side. Note that you have some unnecessary $r$ terms in $\psi_3$. To get from $\psi_1$ to $\psi_2$ use $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta=\mathrm{arctan2}(y,x)$